# Add a new entrypoint to a docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Recently, we decided to move one of our services to docker container. The service is product of another company and they have provided us the docker image. However, we need to do some extra configuration steps in the container entrypoint.

The first thing I tried, was to create a DockerFile from the base image and then add commands to do the extra steps, like this:

```
From baseimage:tag 
RUN chmod a+w /path/to/entrypoint_creates_this_file
```

But, it failed, because these extra steps must be run after running the base container entrypoint.

Is there any way to **extend** entrypoint of a base image? if not, what is the correct way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Is the original entrypoint defines as a single command or a shell script?

If command:

Create an entrypoint script file (or a command) that includes the original command + your configuration commands and change the `ENTRYPOINT` listing in your Dockerfile to use it.

If script:

Create a new script which executes the original entrypoint script and then your own configuration command. Then change the `ENTRYPOINT` listing to point to your new script.

Comment: Thank you Snorre, yes, this is the right solution. The original entrypoint is a shell script and as you said I need to execute it in my custom entry point before other steps.

Comment: Happy to hear that the problem was solved.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finally ended up calling the original entrypoint bash script in my new entrypoint bash script, before doing other extra configuration steps.

Answer (score 7):

You do not need to even create a new Dockerfile. To modify the `entrypoint` you can just run the image using the command such as below:

`docker run --entrypoint new-entry-point-cmd baseimage:tag <optional-args-to-entrypoint>`

Comment: In this way the base image entrypoint will be overtired, while I need to run it first and then run my custom entrypoint.

Answer (score 2):

create your custom entry-point file

-> add this to image

-> specify this as your entrypoint file

```
FROM image:base

COPY /path/to/my-entry-point.sh /my-entry-point.sh
// do sth here

ENTRYPOINT ["/my-entry-point.sh"]
```

Comment: In this way the base image entrypoint will be overtired, while I need to run it first and then my custom entrypoint.

Answer (score 0):

Let me take an example with [certbot](https://hub.docker.com/r/certbot/certbot/). Using the [excellent answer from Anoop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41584749/5362795), we can get an *interactive shell* (`-ti`) into a temporary container (`--rm`) with this image like so:

```bash
$ docker run --rm -ti --entrypoint /bin/sh certbot/certbot:latest
```

But what if we want to run a command *after* the original entry point, like the OP requested? We could run a shell and join the commands as in the following example:

```bash
$ docker run --rm --entrypoint /bin/sh certbot/certbot:latest \
    -c "certbot --version && touch i-can-do-nice-things-here && ls -lah"
certbot 1.30.0
total 28K
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        4.0K Oct  5 15:10 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        4.0K Sep  7 18:10 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           0 Oct  5 15:10 i-can-do-nice-things-here
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        4.0K Sep  7 18:10 src
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        4.0K Sep  7 18:10 tools
```

**Background**

If I run it with the original entrypoint I will get this:

```bash
$ docker run --rm certbot/certbot:latest
```

> Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log Certbot
> doesn't know how to automatically configure the web server on this
> system. However, it can still get a certificate for you. Please run
> "certbot certonly" to do so. You'll need to manually configure your
> web server to use the resulting certificate.

Or:

```bash
$ docker run --rm certbot/certbot:latest --version
certbot 1.30.0
```

I can see the entrypoint with `docker inspect`:

```bash
$ docker inspect certbot/certbot:latest | grep -i entry -C 2
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/opt/certbot",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": null
--
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/opt/certbot",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "certbot"
            ],
```

If `/bin/sh` doesn't work in your container, try `/bin/bash`.