# When I am going to extend mysql docker image, I can't add my own entrypoint shell

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Recently, I am going to create an custom mysql image. I hope it automatically run a custom shell to do some initialization work after mysql server startup. This function will output a SQL result into a local file.

My question is : Though my new init.sh run very successfully (from logs), the container stop immediately after start up few seconds.

When I am doing this work, I refer another post on how to make new entrypoint.sh in custom Dockfile.
[Add a new entrypoint to a docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41582365/add-a-new-entrypoint-to-a-docker-image)

I followed that post contents, created my own 'init.sh'. It includes the invoking of original entrypoint.sh

Dockfile:

```
FROM mysql:5.7
COPY init.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/init.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["init.sh"]
```

init.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
./entrypoint.sh

# here are some custom logic...
echo $PATH
```

I have removed almost all the custom logic in the init.sh. 
As I have said, the image is created successfully, but container can not start up. 
Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: What's the name of the original entrypoint script? I see `entrypoint.sh` in your script but according to [the repo](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/6b1dc54320b03b83a89068f49cc796fea0ff6bb4/5.7/Dockerfile#L72) it should be `docker-entrypoint.sh`. Did you try calling `docker-entrypoint.sh` too?

Comment: use `CMD ["bash", "-c", "/usr/local/bin/init.sh"]` instead of entrypoint

Comment: @flurin I found this code in mysql image dockfile:RUN ln -s usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh.  So /entrypoint.sh link to the docker-entrypoint.sh

Comment: @OscarAkaElvis   I tried to update dockfile by your advice, but it didn't work. It's a same result.

Comment: But your problem is the shell script is not executing? or is executing but is not doing what you want? Because I can see inside init.sh there is another call to other bash script. You need that script on same path and with executable permissions. Maybe that's your problem

Comment: When I use 'docker logs -f containerid' to do a check. I found the value of '$PATH' is printed out as expected. So I feel the init.sh script has been executed and ended without any error. Moreover the permission of mysql docker-entrypoint.sh maybe has been specified in the mysql's dock file.

Comment: My problem is 'though all the scripts have been executed, the container can not up'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have known why my script didn't startup mysql service.
I check the official mysql Dockfile. It specifies 'mysqld' as parameter when running the entrypoint shell file. After I follow the Dockfile, my script startup mysql service successfully.